# How to create a custom UITabBar Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

As I know Apple's UITabBar is pretty much the same, not that much of the customization. What if I want something like [this](https://medium.com/flawless-app-stories/animations-in-ios-tab-bar-concepts-e1fd73ddac67)

Is it just a custom UIView() with gesture recognizers or what's the easiest way of achiveing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I build a custom UITabBar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51540786/how-can-i-build-a-custom-uitabbar)

Answer (score 0):

You have to subclass UITabBarController in order to make your custom TabBar. Here is a very good video link about it:

https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwic5dPfsJDmAhVCOq0KHRQiBvgQwqsBMAB6BAgKEAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DrRhJGnSmEKQ&usg=AOvVaw21E03z-P2OT-CB5mIrNSfP